# Set split to size of file

Tags: split

I have a file that is 9 lines long called foo.txt . I use

```
:split foo.txt
```

and the new split takes up a full 50% of the editor, which results in a lot of wasted space.

I can resize it with `:resize ctrl-R=line('$')` but I have to type it manually each time the file changes because the editor only remembers the evaluated value.

So my question is:

- Is it possible to open a split with maximum height to be the size of the file
- Is it possible to have this happen dynamically, so the size of the split changes (to some maximum) as I add and remove lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly something like

```
augroup resizer
  autocmd!
  autocmd TextChanged * execute 'resize' line('$')
  autocmd TextChangedI * execute 'resize' line('$')
augroup end
```

which should resize the current window as the text is changed (but this may be slow, performance-wise: an alternative would perhaps be `TextChanged` + `InsertLeave`).